# Heroku: NodeJS Express server can't serve image

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, path

I have a simple app on Heruku that show an image.

```
app.js
package.json
package-lock.json
public
   |__ image1.png
   |__ image2.png
```

Here is the content of **app.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    const today = new Date().getHours();
    const img = today <= 13 ? 'image1.png' : 'image2.png';
    response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/' + img));
});
```

In the Heroku log I get this error: **Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/public/image1.png'**

I have made a lot of tries, following these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/40931927/2516399
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25463996/2516399
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26079640/2516399

None of these do the trick in my case. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is at this line `path.join(__dirname, '../public/' + img)`

`__dirname` return directory location where script is being executed.
In your case when you are joining path with '../public' it might be skipping app.js parent dir and selecting `app.js` parent's parent dir. So use `/public` instead `../public` Try below code

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
//app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.get('/', function(request, response) {
    const today = new Date().getHours();
   const img = today <= 13 ? 'image1.png' : 'image2.png';
   console.log(__dirname);
   console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/public', img))
   response.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/public', img));

});
```

Comment: @smartmouse I am gald it helped.